# Evolution of performances in natural language processing tasks

Tags: artificial-intelligence, linguistics

Is there any plots, etc. that show performance metrics on various natural language processing tasks as a function of year.

For example [the following figure](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/facial-recognition-technology-shows-improvement/4796) shows the evolution of performance of face recognition systems:

[image]

I am looking for something similar for natural language processing tasks (e.g. evolution of the perplexity of the state-of-the-art language models, BLUE score of translation systems, accuracy of POS tagging, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

The ACL wiki contains a section on the state-of-the-art systems over time for the main NLP tasks: http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=State_of_the_art

Many of these pages need to be updated but at list there is some attempt of collaborative work to construct a clear overview.

The only survey article the point to dates from 1997 ([Survey of the state of the art in human language technology. Vol. 13. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1997](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1381618411507364126&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)), so I fear there is none more recent.

Excerpt from one of the most satisfying page I found on the ACL wiki:

[image]